# Break the line in a concatenated string based on a matching criteria and add line breaks

Tags: javascript, angular

I am getting a dynamic text from DB via an API call in following format

```
Test 1<br>Test 2<br>Test 3
```

How can I break this string where there is a 'br' tag and add line breaks? I need to show the string in below format

```
Test 1
Test 2
Test 3
```

Can someone please shed some light.

UPDATE: Tried below code, space is being added instead of new line

```
gridData.STATUSNOTES = gridData.STATUSNOTES.replaceAll('<br>', '\n');
```

Comment: If `<br>` is the only text that is inside the string, and you don't have HTML that need to be parsed you can use `string.replaceAll('<br>', '\n')` or `string.replace(/<br>/g, '\n')`. No need to parse as HTML with the DOM where simple replace will do the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Using "br"

You can simply append the text using innerHTML like:

```js
var content = "Test 1<br>Test 2<br>Test 3"
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = content
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

### Using "div"

If it doesn't work, in any case like the parent element doesn't permit, you can make use of `div` or any element with `display` property as `block` as block-level element always starts on a new line and always takes up the full width available. Here's an example of converting your string to be placed in new lines:

```js
var content = "Test 1<br>Test 2<br>Test 3"
var result = "";
content.split("<br>").map(element => result += `<div>${element}</div>`)
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

### UPDATE using "\n" as suggested that OP did not provide whether this is HTML

To do nothing with the HTML but just add a line break in a text, you can replace all `br` with `\n`

```js
const content = 'Test 1<br>Test 2<br>Test 3'.replaceAll('<br>', '\n');
console.log(content);
```

### Update 2 using CSS

If you are looking to use `\n` as a line break stuff, probably you can use a CSS style `white-space: pre-line`. This is a CSS way of breaking lines using `\n`. Hope this helps.

```js
var content = "Test 1<br>Test 2<br>Test 3".replaceAll("<br>","\n")
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = content
```

```html
<div id="result" style="white-space: pre-line;"></div>
```

Comment: I don't think it's good idea, what about if data contain XSS payload it will be just executed.  It make no sense to parse HTML and add to DOM if the input only has `<br>`. OP didn't said anything that the input is HTML.

Comment: '\n' is adding a space instead of breaking the line. I am not sure why

Comment: and I cannot use innerHTML as there is no static parent element, and everything is dynamically generated as it is a grid

Comment: How are you using this string? Are you seeing such space in console? Or inside a tag like `p` tag?

Comment: If you are using this string directly in HTML and wish to see new lines, innerHTML is the way to do it. Use dynamic id along with the dynamic grid that you said, and use that id in javascript as mentioned in my answer. Or as a last update, I have used a CSS way in my answer. Check if that helps.

Comment: Accepted this answer as I was able to make it work using the CSS way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `<br>` with end-of-line code:

```js
const str = 'Test 1<br>Test 2<br>Test 3';
const result = str.replaceAll('<br>', '\n');
console.log(result);
// Test 1
// Test 2
// Test 3
```

Comment: If the input text is not html and only has `<br>` as separator, then this is the right answer.